# Error: Could not find command 'git' with Boxen

Tags: git, shell, boxen

I've installed git with the [installer](http://git-scm.com/download/mac), and it works just fine. I've got the command line tools for git (see below prove), but it seems that when I run Boxen everything is broken.

Does anyone knows which git isn't found by boxen while it is installed? I've also tried to install git through homebrew, but this didn't fix the issue either. Boxen refuses to find git.

Hope you can help.

```
stefan.vermaas at macbook in ~
○ git --version
git version 2.4.3

stefan.vermaas at macbook in ~
○ which git
/usr/local/git/bin/git

stefan.vermaas at macbookx in ~
○ which git
/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/git/bin/git:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin

stefan.vermaas at macbook in /opt/boxen/repo on master
± ./script/boxen
--> Preparing to auto-update...
--> Complete! Nothing new from upstream.
Fact file /opt/boxen/repo/facts.d/example.yaml was parsed but returned an empty data set
Notice: Compiled catalog for macbook in environment production in 2.39 seconds
Error: Could not find command 'git'
```

I've also tried to extend the path like Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen suggested, but it's still saying: "Error: Could not find command 'git'".

Comment: You need to add /usr/local/git/bin to your $PATH variable.  This is a standard exercise with Unix shells.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I've extended the original post with my path. This wasn't the solution.

Comment: Why can't you just use git bundled with xcode (as per the boxen docs)?